# Caracteres con tilde en un arreglo de tipo char

Tags: c, array

Tengo este código:

```
include <stdio.h>

define  TAM 64

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    char cadena[TAM] = {0};

    while (fgets(cadena, sizeof(cadena), stdin) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", cadena);
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto en la consola de GNU/LiNUX e introduzco carácteres como "á" y luego lo imprimo, me lo imprime correctamente. Pero si cadena es un array de char, esto es, el **rango de valores es [2^(8-1) , 2^(8-1)] = [-128, 127]**, con lo cual no debería de poder almacenar y visualizar la tilde  no? Porque es ASCII y habría que usar `unsigned char`.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundido al respecto.

Si introduces `á`, en realidad estas introduciendo **mas de un `char`** (si tienes tu consola configurada para *UTF8*, que es lo habitual hoy dia).

Aquí entra en juego el tema de la **codificación**, que indica la relación entre un código numérico (no necesariamente `char`) y la grafía de un caracter.

Puedes hacer una sencilla comprobación:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  TAM 64

int main( int argc, const char **argv ) {
  char cadena[TAM] = {0};

  while( fgets( cadena, sizeof( cadena ), stdin ) != NULL )
    printf( "bytes: %zu, texto: %s\n", strlen( cadena ), cadena );
}
```

Puedes consultar información extensa al respecto en la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres).